# Difference between Tcpclient and webRequest

Tags: c#, tcpclient, webrequest

I am trying to verify if a website is up or not. i am using TcpClient to make a call to website and it working fine but when i use webrequest for same site it throws a 404 error.

what is the difference in the functionality of TcpClient and webRequest??

```
var client = new TcpClient();
client.Connect("android.clients.google.com", 80);

var request = WebRequest.Create("http://android.clients.google.com");
var resp = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: On the TcpClient you are merely connecting to the server and not retrieving the content of the page requested, while on the second you do get the content. What do you get when you read the stream of the TcpClient?

Comment: What do you mean it's working fine? Your TcpClient code never tries to issue a GET command. WebRequest establishes the connection, sends a GET request and processes the results. WebRequest actually uses TcpClient to issue requests

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> what is the difference in the functionality of TcpClient and webRequest??

A [`TcpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a wrapper around a TCP client socket, letting you communicate with any TCP server. The [application protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_layer) used to communicate with that server is to be implemented by your code. Your code merely connects to the HTTP server, but doesn't communicate with it.

An [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handles not only the TCP layer, but also the [HTTP layer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230). This lets you execute web requests to any HTTP server. Your code executes a `GET` request to `http://android.clients.google.com`, which [doesn't exist](http://android.clients.google.com/), hence the `404` you receive.

To address your original issue: the fact that a web server responds to socket connections on a given port or even returns an HTTP response, may or may not mean the site is considered "up", and so does getting a 200 response. Does receiving [Twitter's "failwhale"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Failwhale.png) mean the site is "up"? Depending on what you're actually trying to do, different approaches may be required. Sometimes it's just best to fire the request you want to, instead of "pinging" the site on beforehand.

Answer (score 0):

404 error meas that the web server is online but there is no such file. The error is returned by the web server, not at client side. In other words, the test is OK. Check the status with really offline web server - you have to get Connection timeout, Port closed or similar. Anyway, for such purpose it is better to use TcpClient.